# Applescript - running handlers from a list

Tags: list, applescript, handler

I'm trying out this code in applescript:

the first one works, the second doesn't

```
global theOpts
on saySomething()
--some code that it runs
end 

set theOpts to {saySomething}

--the one that does

set t to theOpts's item 1
t()

--the one that doesn't

on runByIdx(idx)
    set thefun to item 1 of theOpts
    thefun()
end runByIdx
```

Is there a way I can get this to work?

What I want to do in summary is have a list of handlers that I can call by index rather than by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. It's an undocumented behavior and known design flaw. Handlers aren't meant to be manipulated as objects, and it breaks the handler's bindings to the enclosing script.

The right way to do it is to wrap each handler in its own script object, and put those script objects in the list instead.

```
script Foo
    on doIt()
        say "this"
    end doIt
end script

script Bar
    on doIt()
        say "that"
    end doIt
end script

set opts to {Foo, Bar}

doIt() of item 1 of opts
```

Though you should also not underestimate the value of a simple `if...else if...` block:

```
if idx = 1 then
    doThis()
else idx = 2 then
    doThat()
else ...
```

Basically it depends on what problem you're trying to solve. But I'd lean towards the latter approach (i.e. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) unless it's a task that requires the extra flexibility, otherwise you're just adding unnecessary complexity and making work for yourself.

(FWIW, the [AppleScript book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223618) I co-wrote a few years back has a chapter on working with script objects. The section on libraries doesn't cover the new library system in 10.9+, and the section on OOP has a corker of a technical error if you know where to look:p, but it's probably the best explanation of this subject you'll find so worth a look if you really want to know more.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick, detailed response. This has definitely solved it. I don't yet have the new OS, but I'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

This way both work...

```
global theOpts
on saySomething()
    return 1
end saySomething

set theOpts to {saySomething()}

--the one that does

set t to theOpts's item 1
--t

runByIdx(1)
on runByIdx(idx)
    set thefun to item idx of theOpts
    thefun
end runByIdx
```

Comment: You must have the new version... :(